# ios 9 CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage error when taking pics with iphone

Tags: ios, ios9, gpuimage

Here is the code from a library named GPUImage where throw me an error:

```
err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (kCFAllocatorDefault, coreVideoTextureCache, renderTarget,
                                                                NULL, // texture attributes
                                                                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                                _textureOptions.internalFormat, // opengl format
                                                                (int)_size.width,
                                                                (int)_size.height,
                                                                _textureOptions.format, // native iOS format
                                                                _textureOptions.type,
                                                                0,
                                                                &renderTexture);
```

I used a pod library named DBCamera and it throw me an error when I was trying to take a picture using my iphone.

I think the DBCamera library was using this CPUImage.

I keep pressing the execution button but it just stop there, didn't even log me the error message.

Interesting thing is that the app works if I disconnected from xcode.

here is the [link](https://cocoapods.org/?q=DBCamera) to the library I used

any idea?

Comment: Did you found solution? i got same issue! :(

Comment: @KhatriAbdul not yet.

Comment: Hey, i just downloaded & installed latest version of GPU & it worked!!!